# flex a number with a leading sign, but don't eat addition/subtraction

Tags: regex, lex

I have a flex file based on some PD calculator example I found. I'm expanding it to look for ints vs floats ([as in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57500790/tokenizing-ints-vs-floats-in-lex-flex)). So...

```
"+" |
"-" |
"*" |
"/" |
"(" |
")"     { return yytext[0]; }
```

Then I look for the numbers:

```
(0|[1-9][0-9]*) { yylval.d = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
```

I'd really like to grab the leading sign if it's there:

```
(0|[-+][1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]) { yylval.d = atof(yytext); return NUMBER; }
```

The problem is that Flex looks for the maximal pattern, so:

-10 works, I get "-10"

10-10 fails, I get "10","-10", instead of "10","-","10"

Yes, I know I can handle this in the bison side with an expression looking for unary minus, but it would make the expression syntax cleaner without it and then my yylval would have the proper value from the start. Is there a way to do this entirely on the Flex side?

Comment: By the way, writing a single lexer rule for operators such as  `[-+*/()] { return yytext[0]; }` produces a slightly smaller state table. But I usually just use a default fallback rule, `. { return yytext[0]; }`, because it's even easier and it doesn't need to be modified every time I add a new operator character.

Answer (score 0):

It's theoretically possible to maintain enough context in the lexer to tell whether a given `-` is an infix or prefix operator. But you end up duplicating the work of the parser, which is both pointless (since the parser needs to parse anyway) and bad software design (since two components shouldn't both try to do the same thing).

Adding prefix operators to a parser involves very little additional complication. All you need is one rule for each such operator:

```
expr: '-' expr %prec UNARY { $$ = -$2; }
```

and one additional precedence rule

```
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%precedence UNARY    /* This rule is added */
```

Here `UNARY` is a "pseudotoken" which is never actually generated by the lexer; it exists only to give the unary operator productions a precedence level. The above declaration is sufficient to declare the token; you do not need and additional `%token` declaration.

See the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-precedence-of-operators) for a longer explanation of how precedence declarations work; the manual calls the above example "context-dependent precedence" which I personally think is a misnomer, but it works fine no matter what you call it.)